# Cannot resolve CustomSwipeAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio

I have issue which made me cry all night. I am trying to create program which will show comics pages. I followed tutorial for it, but I am facing error message `Cannot resolve symbol CustomSwipeAdapter`. **Support v4. library** is imported...

I tried: Clean / Rebuild
         Invalidate Chaches / Restart
         Two separate installations of Android Studio 1.4 and 1.5.
         Delete IML. file from project and .idea Folder

**Code here:**

```
package com.example.zlo.berserk;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewParent;

public class volume1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_volume1);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Where is your CustomSwipeAdapter class? You don't import any matching class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because no CustomSwipeAdapter class exists in code.To create a new class by the given name, add a file to your project and name it, "CustomSwipeAdapter".
Now add this code to this file,

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public int getCount() {
  return 3;
} 
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  int resId = 0;
  switch (position) {
       case 0:
           resId = R.layout.swipe1;
           break;
       case 1:
           resId = R.layout.swipe2;
           break;
       case 2:
           resId = R.layout.swipe3;
           break;       
   }
  View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
  ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
  return view;
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
   }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
      return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
 }

 //public boolean isViewFromObject(ViewGroup arg0, Object arg1) {
 // return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
 //}

 @Override
 public Parcelable saveState() {
 return null;
 } 
}
```

When you extend PagerAdapter class, make sure to create few key methods such as getCount(); which defines the size of your pages. In our case it is, 3.
Also,instantiateItem() is to be implemented to inflate the appropriate layout files based on the swipe position. To do that, we have created a switch case that inflates the layout pages (swipe1, swipe2 or swipe3).

Finally you’ll have to create a method destroyItem() to delete the layout page that is longer displayed on the screen. This method will actually free the memory.

Comment: Mister, you saved me. I have clearly much to learn. Thank you